# Error en query dinámico SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql-server

**Solución**

```
    create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Array
    @guia  varchar(8000),
    @Fecha char(4),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''    

    as  
    BEGIN
    declare @vSql  varchar(8000)  

    set  @vSql = 'select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then ''''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','''') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'''')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)       ' 

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = ''00040007''    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = ''SLG''     
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = '''+@Fecha+'''
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  '''+@Prod+'''
    when ''1'' then ''NAC''                                      
    when ''2'' then ''MET''                                      
    when ''3'' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     '

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' and gn.guia_shi_cod = '''+ @Cliente +''' '

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (' + rtrim(ltrim(@guia ))+ ')
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'''')=case when '''+@CodReferenciaFac +''' ='''' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaFac+''' end  
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''')=case when '''+ @CodReferenciaweb +''' ='''' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaweb+''' end   '

    exec (@vSql)

    end
```

********************************FIN DE LA SOLUCIÓN****************************

**Hola, tengo un error en este query dinamico.**

```
    createprocedurespGenBK_Consultar_Array  
    @guia  varchar(max),
    @Fecha char(4),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='''',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''''    


    as  
    declare @vSql  varchar(max)  
    declare @vSql1  varchar(max)  
    declare @vSQL2  varchar(max)
    declare @vSQL3  varchar(max)

    set  @vSql = 'select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then ''''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'''')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)       ' 

    set @vSql1 = ' join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = ''00040007''    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = ''SLG''     
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = '''+@Fecha+'''
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  @Prod                                     
    when ''1'' then ''NAC''                                      
    when ''2'' then ''MET''                                      
    when ''3'' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     '

    set @vsql2 = ' and gn.guia_shi_cod = '''+ @Cliente +''' '

    set @vSQL3 = ' and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (''' + @guia + ''') 
    and gn.guia_shi_cod ='''+@Cliente+'''
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaFac='' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaFac+''' end 
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaweb='' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaweb+''' end  '
    exec (@vSql  +  @vsql1 +  @vsql2 + @vsql3)
```

**Por favor indicarme cual seria la solución, gracias.**

**Error: Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 119
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '00288710'.
Mens. 105, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 158
Falta la comilla de cierre después de la cadena de caracteres '' end    '.**

Comment: Creo que el mensaje es bastante explícito, falta una comilla en la línea 119, sugiero que imprimas a pantalla para que revises cómo se está generando tu SQL dinámico, en lugar del `EXEC` ponle `PRINT @vSql  +  @vsql1 +  @vsql2 + @vsql3`

Comment: Con decirte que la cantidad de lineas de cogido no llega ni a los 110. No existe la línea 119.

Comment: Pero lo que si puedes es hacer la impresión en pantalla del query dinámico, esto te puede dar el lugar exacto de la falla.

Comment: Hola, aquí dejo la solución del query dinámico.

Comment: La sección de preguntas es solo para las preguntas, si encontraste la respuesta la deberías poner como una nueva respuesta y posteriormente marcarla como solucionada ;)

Answer (score 3):

De momento, empezando por el principio... deberías revisar la declaración del Procedimiento:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE spGenBK_Consultar_Array  
    @guia  varchar(max),
    @Fecha char(4),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''
```

Ah, me da que las cuatro comillas que habías puesto es por error porque... si lo que quieres es la cadena vacía lo que te propongo es lo correcto. Lo tuyo asigna un único carácter '
Aparte... después de la clausula AS pondría

```
BEGIN
```

```
END
```

A continuación... yo iría de menos a más. Asignaría primero al SQL Dinámico la mínima expresión y en lugar de EXEC pondría PRINT:

```
PRINT (@vSql  +  @vsql1 +  @vsql2 + @vsql3)
```

Eso te mostrará en pantalla la sentencia que se va a ejecutar. Puedes copiarla y pegarla en otra ventana de SQL y verás en seguida lo que está mal.

Comment: Ya modifique unas cuantas cosas y logro listar, pero tengo otro problema, no esta funcionando esto: and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''')=case when '''+@CodReferenciaweb+'''='''' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaweb+''' end '  ¿Que deberia modificar para que ese parametro sea considerado en mi consulta?. Esto es lo que aparece en el print : and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'')=case when ''='' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'') else '' end

Comment: Pegando el texto que genera el PRINT en una nueva ventana me encuentra el primer error en  < replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'',') as Consignatario, > el problema lo tienes en ,') as  esa comilla debería ser doble

Comment: Ok, ya esta modificado, ahora solo me falta lo que te comento, esto no me sale: and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''')=case when '''+ @CodReferenciaweb =''''+''' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaweb+''' end ' --> Si lo dejo asi me da error.

Comment: Pasa algo parecido... en la línea de antes tienes < else ''' end > hay tres comillas, te sobra una

Comment: Ah, y en la última pasa lo mismo

Comment: Listo, modifique todo y ya lista. Solo faltaría el ultimo problema. (Por cierto, gracias por tu tiempo). Estoy mandando varios campos en una de las variables pero me sale este error de longitud: Mens. 103, Nivel 15, Estado 4, Línea 106
El identificador que comienza por '
'1010968487-1','1010968485-2', '1010968486-3', '1010968489-4', 
'1010979641-1', '1010979641-2', '1010962269-1', '1010962270-2' es demasiado largo. La longitud máxima es 128.

Comment: Pues... no sé pero... veo que también están mal las últimas dos líneas en lo mismo: < and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,')=case when @CodReferenciaFac=' then > el ISNULL necesitaría dos comillas y no solo una

Comment: Ah, sobre lo anterior... fíjate que empieza por dos comillas... debería ser solo una

Comment: Si todo eso ya esta solucionado, solo faltaría ver el tema de la longitud. Yo he colocado el tipo de variable varchar(max) y no se por que no alcanza.

Comment: Uf... hacer esto así a ciegas... no es fácil pero... he visto 3 gazapos más... en la línea <and gdn.pro_cod = case  @ Prod  > debes sustituir @Prod por su valor como haces justo la línea de antes con @ Fecha y... lo mismo en las dos últimas líneas. El problema del SQL Dinámico es que es difícil de depurar, por eso lo más efectivo es PRINT @ SQL y ves qué sentencia está lanzando.